# How to install MFOC

Tags: software-installation

I want to install MFOC (MiFare classic Offline Cracker). I have found [this site](http://nfc-tools.org/index.php?title=MFOC) that references me to the [git hub project](https://github.com/nfc-tools/mfoc) and cloned it. But I have no idea how to install/run this. Could you help me?

Answer (score 2):

The project is now hosted on Github :

```
git clone https://github.com/nfc-tools/mfoc.git
cd mfoc
autoreconf -vis
./configure
sudo make
sudo make install
```

Answer (score 0):

`cd` into your cloned repo directory.

Then run,

```
./configure
```

and fix dependencies issues if any. Then run,

```
make
make install
```

Comment: I was thinking about this approach, but there is no configure in the directory

Answer (score 0):

From a [.pdf on the developers web site](http://www.nicolascourtois.com/MifareClassicHack.pdf), here is how to install MFOC on Ubuntu.

First we need to add some dependacies

```
sudo apt-get install checkinstall build-essentials
```

Now get and install this version

```
wget http://code.google.com/p/nfc-tools/downloads/detail?name=mfoc-0.10.2.tar.gz
tar -xzvf mfoc-0.10.2.tar.gz
cd mfoc-0.10.2
autoreconf -vis
./configure
sudo make
```

You can use it from here `./mfoc -O card_dump`, or use `checkinstall` to package it and install it to the system

```
sudo checkinstall
mfoc -O card_dump
```