# Unable to run MFOC -O

Tags: nfc

After installing according to [How to install MFOC](https://askubuntu.com/questions/737300/how-to-install-mfoc)

I am currently using ubuntu on VM oracle

I connected ACR122U card reader and ran `mfoc -O`

The reader's indicator is lit so I think the reader is working fine

pcsc_scan is able to detect the reader and card

```
$ mfoc -O mycard.mfd
info    libnfc.config    Unable to open file: /etc/nfc/libnfc.conf
debug    libnfc.config    Unable to open directory: /etc/nfc/devices.d
unknown    libnfc.general    log_level is set to 3
debug    libnfc.general    allow_autoscan is set to true
debug    libnfc.general    allow_intrusive_scan is set to false
debug    libnfc.general    0 device(s) defined by user
No NFC device found.
```

Comment: I would start by using `sudo` since it is device related I'd assume you need to be admin.

Comment: Tried you suggestion and it still gives me back the same description, thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue that is solved for me by running `sudo modprobe -r pn533_usb` and `sudo modprobe -r pn533`
You can also check if you can reed the card with `sudo nfc-list`